# Why wasn't my wire transfer delivered to my client's account in Turkey?

Tags: united-states, bank-account, international-transfer, turkey

I was told initially that an international wire transfer normally takes 2 to 3 business days to deliver to my client in Turkey, but it has been more than 10 days now since I made the transfer and I have been debited. I asked my bank to track the transfer and we found out that the money is already in Turkey, but was unable to deposit in my clients account. What could be the possible reason for the rejection of the wire? Could it be because I made the wire transfer in USD to his Euro account?

Comment: "Did" or "did not"?

Comment: What reason did the bank give for the delay?

Comment: If you paid USD to his Euro account, *someone* will have to exchange USD to Euro, arranging that could easily take time.  You should have used Transferwise which can *easily* transfer USD to EUR (or even USD to TRY).

Comment: Surely this is a question your bank or the receiving bank can answer more accurately than any of us.

Comment: Are you sure he has a Euro account in turkey ?? Seems strange.